# Elasticsearch Aggs Join Logic

Tags: elasticsearch

I am writing a query with elasticsearch. I got stuck in one last place. I couldn't figure out the logic of Join. I have a blog table. And I made some scoring in this blog table. Example (**Reading** = 1, **Like** = 5, **Comment** = 10) points. I have been ranked according to these points and the last 1 week. I have no problems so far.

**Mapping**

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "properties": {
      "blog_id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "created_at": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "point": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "status": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "type": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "updated_at": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "user_id": {
        "type": "long"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query brings scores.

```
{
    "body": {
        "from": 0,
        "size": 3,
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "range": {
                            "created_at": {
                                "lte": "now"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "range": {
                            "created_at": {
                                "gte": "now-7d"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "filter": [
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "status": 1
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "total": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "blog_id",
                    "order": {
                        "amount.value": "DESC"
                    }
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "amount": {
                        "sum": {
                            "field": "point"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Response Agg

```
{
    "total": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": 1,
                "doc_count": 3,
                "amount": {
                    "value": 16
                }
            },
            {
                "key": 2,
                "doc_count": 1,
                "amount": {
                    "value": 5
                }
            },
            {
                "key": 8,
                "doc_count": 1,
                "amount": {
                    "value": 1
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now, my question is how can I combine the id numbers written in the key with another index?

Comment: What is the "**another index**" here?

Comment: Example : blog table ( index )

Comment: This index also has the same mapping?

Comment: Yes partially. I want to match the points.blog_id and blog.id fields.

Comment: Are you looking for MySQL like join? Note that elasicsearch doesn't support joins on multiple indices. But you can always target more than one index using a single get request.

Comment: Yes I think like mysql. Isn't it possible to do this with elasticsearch?

Comment: No, elastic search is not built to be a relational DB.

Comment: Thank you. So how can we solve this problem without losing speed. Do you have a suggestion? So without adding php or any other programming language.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214228/discussion-between-opster-es-ninja-nishant-and-ozgur-can-karagoz).